# Error al instalar MS Deploy

Tags: windows, iis

Ayuda me sale el siguiente error al ejecutar el instalador de ms deploy (web deploy) lo intente con el de 32 bits con el de 64 bits en ingles y español, como administrador y persiste el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre la Solucion Hice una búsqueda y una solución común es iniciar el servicio "Windows Installer" una vez iniciado ejecutar el instalador msi nuevamente como administrador y deja de salir el mensaje de error, Saludos.